# Parse SQL XML back into SQL columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

My query returns all calls made. I need to separate the returning XML values into just 4 columns:

**FirstCallDate, SecondCallDate, ThirdCallDate, LastCallDate.**

Current Query:

```
SELECT AllCalls FROM
(
SELECT  
          (  SELECT startdate
            FROM mycalls i WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE i.phone = d.phone  FOR XML AUTO)
            AS AllCalls

  FROM [MYDB].[dbo].[Accounts] d WITH (NOLOCK)   
  WHERE SubmittedDate BETWEEN @MyStartDate AND @MyEndDate

) e
```

This will return sometimes:

- NULL
- i startdate="2012-02-29T13:50:37"/>
- i startdate="2012-02-29T14:20:58"/>i startdate="2012-02-29T14:21:13"/> (removed start bracket)
- 3 + dates
- 4 + dates
- 5 + dates
- etc

So my return query should look like the sql below, but each column should only hold 1 date.

```
    SELECT FirstCallDate, SecondCallDate, ThirdCallDate, LastCallDate
 FROM
    (
    SELECT  
              (  SELECT startdate
                FROM mycalls i WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE i.phone = d.phone  FOR XML AUTO)
                AS AllCalls

      FROM [MYDB].[dbo].[Accounts] d WITH (NOLOCK)   
      WHERE SubmittedDate BETWEEN @MyStartDate AND @MyEndDate

    ) e
```

Any ideas on how to parse the XML back into SQL columns?

Answer (score 1):

The built-in XML parser allows you to turn the XML back into rows, not columns.  The only possible thing you can do is basically "undo" the XML aggregation. Please see the topic of XML in SQL server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189887.aspx. This sub-topic I used for reference on name-spaces:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177400.aspx.

From there you could pivot the results as you will. I have adapted your query to do this:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('uri' as ns1)
SELECT phone, [1] AS FirstCall, [2] As SecondCall, [3] As ThirdCall, [4] As LastCall
FROM   (SELECT RN, phone, IndexRef
        FROM   (SELECT phone, CAST((SELECT StartDate as 'ns1:StartDate'
                      FROM   mycalls i WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE i.phone = d.phone FOR XML RAW('ns1:Prod'), ELEMENTS) AS XML) AS AllCalls
                FROM   [mydb].[dbo].[Accounts] d
                WHERE  phone in (31304,35549,39794,42711,51201,52529)) ns1
               CROSS APPLY (SELECT row_number() over (order by relop.value('.','DateTime')) RN, relop.value('.','DateTime') AS CallLog 
                              FROM ns1.AllCalls.nodes( N'//ns1:StartDate') AS ro(relop)) r) X
       PIVOT(MAX(CallLog) FOR RN IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])) P
```

Obviously, for this query, the XML is simply bloat in the middle and can be skipped.(Query to follow). Still, this method is useful if you are bound to XML output from some source other than a direct query.

Without using XML, it's much easier.

```
SELECT P.phone, p.[1] AS FirstCallDate, p.[2] AS SecondCallDate, p.[3] AS ThirdCallDate, p.[4] AS LastCallDate
FROM   (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.phone ORDER BY i.StartDate) i.phone, CallOrder, StartDate
        FROM   [mydb].[dbo].[Accounts] d
               JOIN mycalls i ON d.phone = i.phone
        WHERE  d.SubmittedDate BETWEEN @MyStartDate AND @MyEndDate) X
       PIVOT (MAX(StartDate) FOR CallOrder IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])) P
```

What you won't be able to do in context of SQL is create a pivot with an arbitrary number of columns (thought that sure would be nice!)

Answer (score 0):

You are using XML to aggregate the data by account.  I'm thinking you avoid XML altogether and use a ROW_NUMBER() OVER() construct to get the last 4 calls within the date range for each account and then pivot using the PIVOT operator.